# How to have maven automatically build assembly submodule after new submodules

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project that uses the assembly plugin to create an archive of all the binaries produced by the submodules. As recommended [in this article](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html), I put my assembly descriptor in a new submodule called distribution. The assembly works properly, but has to build after all of the other submodules.

Developers routinely create new submodules using the maven-archetype-quickstart archetype, which adds the new submodule to the end of the  section in the parent POM. The build will then not work correctly unless either the  section in the parent POM is re-sorted, or the new submodule is added as a dependency of the distribution submodule.

Is there any way to avoid having to do one of these manual steps each time a new submodule is added?

Comment: Have you tried to run the assembly plugin in a later phase like pre-integration-test instead of package?

Comment: I went gave that I try, but it did not work. It is my understanding that each submodule is taken through the entire lifecycle before the next module is built, so attaching to a different phase would not help.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't that mean that this `distribution` submodule depends on the other submodules (and basically everything)? If you phrase the dependency hierarchy out in the pom, this would cause the `distribution` submodule to be built after all of it's dependencies. WHta this means that you can specify the other modules or submodules in the `dependencies` section of `distribution`'s pom.

Comment: I understand that the distribution submodule will build last if I make it depend on everything else. My question is whether there is any way to avoid having to edit the distribution submodule to add a new dependency every time a new submodule is added to the project.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know that from top of my head. But I see what you are saying, that would be good for maintenance perspective.